# Generate controller and dashboard for adminstrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I am using administrate gem for admin panel .I want to generate a new dashboard and controller "demo" for administrate. I use this command
"rails generate administrate:dashboard Demo" but is shows error

```
home/dev7/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/administrate-0.1.4/lib/generators/administrate/dashboard/dashboard_generator.rb:107:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Demo (NameError)
```

help me with this

Comment: I am not familiar with the gem but it might search for the class that is explicitly named `Demo`. Perhaps you don't have a model that is called like that or it's in a namespace?

Comment: I just want to create a new page with url "/admin/demo/". I want to create it without a model.

Comment: The generator `administrate:dashboard` is specific for models. What do you want to show on your demo dashboard?

Comment: I want to show some widgets on a  page with custom css, for that I just want to create a simple page on admin panel. In present condition I am not able to create new page .All pages are created by administrate itself

Comment: can't you just make it manually then, without generators?

Comment: Yes , I tried that .I manually create controller and dashboard but it show error "uninitialized constant demo".